# Computational Complexity of `HashSet::len` in Rust

Tags: rust, collections, hashmap, time-complexity, hashset

I'm currently working with Rust's `HashSet` and I'm trying to understand the computational complexity of the `HashSet::len` operation.

The Rust documentation provides information about the computational complexity of `get` and `insert` operations for `HashMap` being O(1) on average, but it doesn't explicitly mention the complexity for `HashSet` or the `len` operation.

In general, the len operation for many data structures is O(1), but I couldn't find a specific statement confirming this for `HashSet::len` in Rust.
Here's the link to the relevant Rust documentation: [Rust Collections](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/index.html#maps)

Could anyone clarify the computational complexity of `HashSet::len`? Is it O(1) as I would expect, or is there a different complexity associated with this operation in Rust's `HashSet`?

Comment: It's basically impossible to implement a hash map that does not keep track of the current number of elements, since you need to resize once a certain percentage of elements is filled. I don't think there is any hash map implementation in actual use that has a `len()` implementation with a runtime complexity of more than O(1). I can't find a statement to that end in the documentation, but it's the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: Related discussion mentioning that `.len()` is O(1) for all standard lib collections: https://github.com/rust-lang/api-guidelines/discussions/149

Comment: Note that for `HashSet` operations, the docs you linked state that: "_For Sets, all operations have the cost of the equivalent Map operation._" But you're right that the complexity of `len` is undocumented.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had to go down a bit of a rabbit hole for this one. In short, reading the source code from `std::collections::HashMap` indicates that the standard HashMap inherits its `len()` functionality from the crate `hashbrown`, which is a Rust port of the Google HashTable variant, SwissTable ([github](https://github.com/rust-lang/hashbrown)). Tracking down the implementation of `len()` in this crate leads down to the underlying class, `RawTable`, which contains an instance of `RawTableInner<A>`, generic for the entry type `A`. This struct contains a slot called `items : usize` which is returned whenever `len()` is called. This indicates that the `len()` function simply returns the value of an internally stored integer count which keeps track of the number of entries.

Overall, this suggests that the time complexity of `len()` will be O(1), as it isn't doing any iteration or counting, but rather simply return the value of an entry counter which has been maintained over the course of the HashTable's construction.